# Is it possible to factory reset an arduino from hardware to remove bad user code?

Tags: arduino, stm32, arduino-ide, stm32f4

I was troubleshooting why Serial1 was always throwing undefined errors in sketches I was trying to run when I found a solution posted online for a slightly different board that suggested this line:

`HardwareSerial Serial1(2);`

I uploaded it and now the Arduino doesn't show up in the IDE, did I remap it's serial communications? Why is this possible!

Is there any hardware factory reset option available on these boards? Did I just brick my device?

**edit:** It seems the STM32Cube programmer app can be used to communicate with the device but I'm not sure where to get the original firmware to flash. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbshM.jpg

Comment: https://www.stm32duino.com

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the tag in your question, I guess you have an STM32 – (BluePill) Development Board (STM32F103C8).

If you think that your board is not handling serial communication properly then you might consider burning bootloader to your board. This will reset the complete configuration of your board.

There are many ways in which you can burn bootloader to your board.

1. Using another Arduino board like Uno / Nano / Mega
2. Using an FTDI USB to TTL Serial Adapter.

You might want to go through tutorials list below:

1. [Getting Started with STM32 using Arduino IDE: Blinking LED](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/getting-started-with-stm32-development-board-stm32f103c8-using-arduino-ide)
2. [Programming STM32F103C8 Board using USB Port](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/programming-stm32f103c8-board-using-usb-port)

Comment: Hi @sourabh, I'm using an STM32f405

Comment: Oh, I guess most of the tutorial remains the same. You will require a USB to FTDI Programmer to burn the bootloader. It will reset everything to default.

Comment: you don't need a programmer. a normal USB to TTL Serial adapter will do

Comment: @Juraj Yes, it will. Actually, by a programmer, I meant that adapter only. Sorry for misleading. Updated the answer.

Comment: @juraj & sourabh I downloaded the manufacturers tool called stm32cube programmer which seems to recognize the device plugged in even though serial coms in arduino IDE don't work. It lets me flash a new firmware so I think I can use this but I'm unsure where to get the factory firmware.

Comment: @altShiftDev, Awesome!, Seems, like you will be finally able to reset it to factory default. I guess for a stm32cube programmer software, my answer won't be of much use. You need to find some other resources, like YouTube/ Articles on it.

Comment: @SourabhChoure I found some bootloader firmware to flash but it turns out that erasing the code using this tool doesn't actually erase user uploaded memory so that didn't help. I'll look into buying a device like you suggested if you still think it can access more memory than just a USB connection?